# by = argument not working with dplyr::slice_sample()

Tags: dplyr

I'm getting the following error message when I try to use the dplyr::slice_sample() function with the 'by =' argument. Here's a simple example:

```
years_ <- c(1979, 1980, 1980, 1981, 1982)
x <- tibble(year_ = years_, yvar = 1:5)
x
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  year_  yvar
  <dbl> <int>
1  1979     1
2  1980     2
3  1980     3
4  1981     4
5  1982     5

x %>% slice_sample(n=1, by = year_, replace = TRUE)
Error in `slice_sample()`:
! `...` must be empty.
✖ Problematic argument:
• by = year_
```

I've also tried using .by instead of by and placing the year_ variable in quotes (i.e. by = "year_") but am still getting the same issue.

Am I doing something incorrectly? I'm using version 1.0.10 of dplyr.

Comment: Strange. Your code works fine for me (in dplyr 1.1.1). Can you try running the code again in a new R session with nothing else in the environment?

Comment: It looks like the issue was with my older version of dplyr. I started a new, clean R session, but got the same error. I then tried the example on another machine with dplyr 1.1.0 and the code ran without errors. Thank you very much for your helpful response.